# How to decode a base64 string and select input charset using php?

Tags: php, character-encoding, base64, decode, windows-1252

How to decode a base64 string and select input charset using php?

For example it works correctly here : https://www.base64decode.org

I want decode a base64 string using **php** and I want select **Windows-1252** charset.

I use this code:

```
base64_decode($encode);
```

But it doesn't show Windows-1252 charset!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Let's see some actual examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode with the `base64_decode($encode);`, but then you can use the `iconv()` to convert the character set to the one you want. You have to know what character set the `$encode` data is using first.

For example if the `$encode` data was using **utf-8** the use the following:

```
$decoded = base64_decode($encode);
$text = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $decoded);
```

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php